# Extract characters between two characters R

Tags: r

I have a df and I want to extract the tissue name between the './' and '.v8'
So for this df the result would be a column with just 'Thyroid', 'Esophagus_Muscularis', Adipose_Subcutaneous

```
gene<-c("ENSG00000065485.19","ENSG00000079112.9","ENSG00000079112")
tissue<-c("./Thyroid.v8.signif_variant_gene_pairs.txt.gz","./Esophagus_Muscularis.v8.signif_variant_gene_pairs.txt.gz","./Adipose_Subcutaneous.v8.signif_variant_gene_pairs.txt.gz")
df<-data.frame(gene,tissue)
```

I really struggle with regex and tried:

```
pattern="/.\(.*)/.v8(.*)"
result <- regmatches(df$tissue,regexec(pattern,df$tissue))
```

but I get:

> Error: '(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
>   ""/.("

Comment: `qdapRegex::ex_between(df$tissue, "/", ".v8")`

Comment: How do I make this a column of strings rather than a list??

Comment: `unlist` them, `unlist(qdapRegex::ex_between(df$tissue, "/", ".v8"))`

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, we need to escape (`\`).  Here, we used a regex lookaround that matches the word (`\\w+`) which succeeds the `.` (metacharacter - escaped) and the `\`, followed by the `.` (`\\` escape) and 'v8'

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(new = str_extract(tissue, "(?<=\\.[/])\\w+(?=\\.v8)"))
#             gene                                                     tissue                  new
#1 ENSG00000065485.19              ./Thyroid.v8.signif_variant_gene_pairs.txt.gz              Thyroid
#2  ENSG00000079112.9 ./Esophagus_Muscularis.v8.signif_variant_gene_pairs.txt.gz Esophagus_Muscularis
#3    ENSG00000079112 ./Adipose_Subcutaneous.v8.signif_variant_gene_pairs.txt.gz Adipose_Subcutaneous
```

The `(?<=\\.[/])` - is a positive lookbehind to match the `.` and the `/` that precedes the word (`\\w+`), and `(?=\\.v8)` - positive lookahead to match the `.` and string 'v8' after the word.  So, basically, it looks for a word that have a pattern before and after it and extracts the word

Comment: Wow! That works - thankyou. Could you explain the regex? I understand the '\\.' is escaping the special character '.' and I think \\w+ is any word or character but don't know the rest?

Comment: @zoe Thank you.  I updated with some description

Comment: Hi @akrun, Apologies but I have some rows that have a '-' in the string eg 
 './Cells_EBV-transformed_lymphocytes.v8.signif_varianiant_gene_pairs.txt.gz' which I think is resulting in 'NA'. Is there a way to catch the '-' also??

Comment: @zoe Would that make the dupe link not a dupe?